# Editing windows Registry on a Network

Tags: windows-registry

I am trying to edit the registry of a system in the network.But I am getting an error message when i try open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE of the system in the network.How to edit the registry of the system in network.I want to disable the USB port of that System in Network.
I have opened the registry of the system using **connect network registry** in regedit.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting to the Registry on another computer is straightforward, provided you meet the pre-requisites.

**Pre-requisites**

1. The Remote Registry service has started on both machines.

   - Click on the Start Button, in the Start Search dialog box, type: 'Services'.
   - Scroll down the list of services until you come to the 'Rs', right-click Remote Registry, and select Start from the short-cut menu.
   - One of my beliefs is that anything that you can do manually, you can do with a VBScript.
2. You logon as an administrator.
3. You can connect to the other machine by typing the UNC path (\ machine) in the Start Search dialog box.

**Instructions**

1. Launch Regedit, and click on the File menu
2. Look for, Connect Network Registry.
3. In the Select Computer dialog box, type the name of the machine you wish to connect.  Click OK.
4. Optionally, click 'Check Names'
5. If that does not work, investigate the Advanced settings.

[image]

from [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vista/vista_registry_remote.htm)